# Darken Javadoc Background Colour

Tags: java, eclipse, themes, javadoc

I'm currently using a customised dark theme for Eclipse including the UI and editor. The only problem is that the Javadoc and scrollbars aren't darkened. I don't mind having normal scrollbars, and I think that's to do with the OS theme. Is it possible to change the background colour of the Javadoc and still have it work in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps adjusting preferences in Eclipse manually will solve your problem?
Try opening the preferences dialog in Eclipse and navigate to General -> Appearance -> Colors and fonts. In the Colors and fonts section navigate to Java -> Javadoc view background. Then just edit it. :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that after spending an hour configuring the theme. Thank you for that!